# SP: handling nulls

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this Table structure:

```
Id int not null --PK
Title varchar(50)
ParentId int null --FK to same Table.Id
```

I'm writing a SP that returns a row's "brothers", here's the code

```
select * from Table
where Table.ParentId = (select Table.ParentId from Table where Table.id = @Id)
and Table.Id <> @Id
```

It works perfectly for rows having a parent, but for those who's parent are null (root records), it returns no row. This is working as expected since `null = null` is always false.

I'm looking for help on how to better design my SP to handle this specific case. I'm not a DBA and my TSQL knowledge is basic.

EDIT: I've updated my SQL query like this:

```
DECLARE @Id INT
SET @Id = 1

DECLARE @ParentId INT
SET @ParentId = (SELECT Table.ParentId FROM Table WHERE Table.Id = @Id)

SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE (
    (@ParentId IS NULL AND (Table.ParentId IS NULL))
    OR (Table.ParentId = @ParentId)
)

AND Table.Id <> @Id
```

It does do the job but if the Id is not in the table, it still returns the row who have no parents. Going to lunch, continue looking at this later.

Thanks in advance,
Fabian

Comment: possible duplicate of [Avoiding IF ELSE due to variable been NULL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19682956/avoiding-if-else-due-to-variable-been-null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the best solution, but you could try to use the [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) operator using a "not valid" id for NULL

```
select * from Table
where COALESCE(Table.ParentId,-1) = (select COALESCE(Table.ParentId,-1) from Table where Table.id = @Id)
and Table.Id <> @Id
```

Assuming -1 is never used as an ID

Comment: This isn't sargable though so is only suitable for small tables.

Comment: Nice solution, it does the work and my table will never have more than 200 records.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible I have not understood your problem description however, in order to return Brothers only when they exist for a given Parent, the following query should suffice:

```
  select Brother.* 
    from Table Parent
        inner join Table Brother on
          Parent.id = Brother.ParentID
    where Parent.Id= @Id and Brother.Id <> @Id
```

Comment: Aren't you still going to end up doing an equality with NULL here `Parent.id = Brother.ParentID`?

Comment: @Martin Smith: Parent.id = NULL should return no Brother records, which I believe is the desired outcome?

Comment: My interpretation was that all records with `NULL` ParentID values should be treated as brothers. I guess in that case it might be easier to use a sentinel `ParentID` value of 0 or something rather than `NULL` to get the desired equality semantics.

Comment: @Martin, I can't because the links are automatically resolved to build a hierary graph of objects. My last edit is a nice solution I think, still need to address one issue.

Comment: @Martin Smith: Ah ok... so all Brothers with a NULL ParentID are to be treated as their own set? Which is a bit naughty from a data domain definition perspective but as you suggest, a sentinel value could provide the solution.