# Compare NULL to NULL in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, null

I have some code where variable used in the WHERE clause could be nullable. As a result I have to query data using IF ELSE to check for NULL. Is there anyway of writing in in one query?

```
DECLARE @OrderID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

IF @OrderID IS NULL 
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM Customers
    WHERE OrderID IS NULL
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM Customers
    WHERE OrderID = @OrderID
END
```

Comment: fixed copy paste error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM Customers
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT OrderID INTERSECT SELECT @OrderID)
```

Will do this efficiently.

See [Undocumented Query Plans: Equality Comparisons](http://web.archive.org/web/20180422151947/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/06/22/undocumented-query-plans-equality-comparisons.aspx) for more about this.

Comment: @PaulSnow I've no idea what you mean by that. But, yes, you can use it in a join condition if that's what you are asking. `CREATE TABLE #T1(X INT NULL UNIQUE);CREATE TABLE #T2(X INT NULL UNIQUE);SELECT * FROM #T1 JOIN  #T2 ON EXISTS(SELECT #T1.X INTERSECT SELECT #T2.X);DROP TABLE #T1, #T2`

Comment: @MartinSmith, any difference to `WHERE OrderID is NULL and @OrderID is NULL or OrderID = @OrderID` ?

Comment: @i-one - Not as far as I'm aware. Both can give a plan with an index seek on `OrderID`

Comment: We have numerous code in SPs that check for and logs changes to Column values when updating a Row.  Based on this Answer, I derived the following for equality comparisons of Nullable values while treating a Null as a comparable value.

`
declare @a int = null
declare @b int = 1

--Equality comparisons treating Nulls as comparable values:

--If (@a = @b), ...
if exists (select @a intersect select @b) select 'true' as [=] else select 'false' as [=] 

--If (@a != @b), ...
if not exists (select @a intersect select @b) select 'true' as [!=] else select 'false' as [!=]
`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want all records where order_id is either null or equal to a provided order ID, using COALESCE will keep the original order ID if not null but yield the provided order ID if it *was* null. That is then compared with the provided order ID.

```
SELECT *
FROM customers c
WHERE COALESCE(c.order_id, @OrderID) = @OrderID;
```

---

Based on the correct version of the query, I'd either write it all out in the WHERE clause, or possibly COALESCE both sides to a value that is known not to appear in that column *ever*.

```
SELECT c.*
FROM customers c
WHERE (@OrderID IS NULL AND c.OrderId IS NULL) OR c.OrderId = @OrderId

-- OR

SELECT c.*
FROM customers c
WHERE COALESCE(@OrderId, '@@@') = COALESCE(c.OrderId, '@@@')
```

Comment: does not give desired results

Comment: Interpreted your question differently, based on the version that still had the copy + paste error.

Comment: none of these solution work for my case when the value of @OrderID is null

Answer (score 0):

**SQL Server 2022 and Azure** now supports the [`IS [NOT] DISTINCT FROM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/is-distinct-from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) syntax. This will do a proper null comparison.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM Customers
WHERE OrderID IS NOT DISTINCT FROM @OrderID;
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
DECLARE @OrderID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE ISNULL(@OrderID, 0) = 0 or @OrderID = @OrderID
```