# where condition in TSQL based on input parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an sql server table with an int  column named [type] which is nullable. I have following stored procedure which gets type as input:

```
    @Jobtype VARCHAR(50) = '',  
    @Language INT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT [TabId]      
      ,CASE
            WHEN @Language = 2 THEN [TabNameTextLang2]
            ELSE [TabNameTextLang1]
        END AS TabName
      ,CASE
            WHEN @Language = 2 THEN [PageTitleLang2]
            ELSE [PageTitleLang1]
        END AS PageTitle
      ,[TabLink]
      ,[Type]
      ,[Priority]
      ,[DutyStationId]
      ,[DateCreated]
      ,[DateModified]
      ,[Deleted]
    FROM dbo.hr_Tabs
    WHERE Deleted = 0 AND 
    ((@Jobtype = '' and [Type] is null) or  ([Type] = CASt(@Jobtype as int )))

END
```

this table has a row where type is null. I want that when i pass @jobtype as '' then only that row is selected otherwise rows are shown by their type. But when I try to pass above stored procedure parameters like

```
exec myproce '', 1
```

I get all records

Please suggest how to filter records based on type in my case

Comment: Do you get all rows, or just all rows where `type` is 0? `CAST('' as int)` produces a 0, so the second part of the condition could be true.

Comment: all rows where type is 0 or null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
((@Jobtype = '' and [Type] is null) or
 (@Jobtype <> '' and [Type] = CAST(@Jobtype as int )))
```

(I would also generally suggest to use `NULL` rather than an empty string as your special marker value)

Comment: in that case I will use following ? ((@Jobtype is null and [Type] is null) or
 (@Jobtype is not null and [Type] = @Jobtype))

Answer (score -1):

Alternative

```
FROM dbo.hr_Tabs
CROSS APPLY (select [Type] as dummy intersect select nullif(@Jobtype, '')) x
WHERE Deleted = 0
```

In order to get an exact match to mr. Smith's answer (logic is the same):

```
FROM dbo.hr_Tabs
WHERE Deleted = 0 and exists 
(select [Type] as dummy intersect select nullif(@Jobtype, ''))
```

Comment: Normal procedure is to comment when downvoting. This syntax is valid

Comment: I was inspired by this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19682956/avoiding-if-else-due-to-variable-been-null/19683011#19683011) by @MartinSmith